# Log file viewer

Tags: text-editors, logging, viewer

I would like to know if any log file viewer is developed for windows platform , which **"updates"** the log file instead ****refreshing the whole content** every time** in the log file all the time.

-Srinivas

Answer (score 2):

There is [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/), assuming you are basically looking for a Windows tail solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. **[Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)** (mentioned by Rich) is a light-weight solution.
2. If you are Notepad++ user, you may install **[Document Monitor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#D)** plugin to "tail" the file.

If these solutions don't suit your need, you may find many alternatives in a similar question in StackOverflow ([How to monitor a text file in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632/how-to-monitor-a-text-file-in-realtime)).

Answer (score 1):

The open source program [Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) would suit you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ReflectInsight](http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/).  It does everything you asked for and more.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the developers for ReflectInsight.

[image]